# Postgres CITEXT working when querying in DBeaver but not working when calling through an API in postman or swagger

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a database where I have a column that is of CITEXT datatype to allow for case insensitive search.  When I test the query select * from DB where description = 'tEsT'; it returns what I want in a case insensitive way.

But when I have an API call which uses that column and has a case insensitive search it doesn't work at all.  It is strange since it is working when querying the DB directly, but not when being called through an API and the service is making the call.

I can provide more information if I need to.

Comment: Are you using the same provider (driver) in both cases?

Comment: What do you mean the same provider?  Like the search_path or schema?  How would I check that for the DB to then check my service.

Comment: The connection string.  See top of following : https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Comment: Is it inside a function in Postgres?

Comment: CITEXT is a datatype that uses a lower on both the value being retrieved and the values in the DB to check making it case insensitive.  

Yes they are on the same driver and schema.  @jdweng

Comment: Try removing the WHERE from the query and check results.  Want to find out is the output shows the lower case.  Are you using a parameter in the query string in c#?  Usually cases like this you are not using a parameter and then the driver guesses types.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this case is that CITEXT when you add the extension with

```
create extension if not exist citext;
```

It defaults to the public schema.  So when the API was calling the service with our schema it wasn't working.

```
alter extension citext schema actualCorrectSchema
```

You can also alter the extension to turn on the ability for it to jump between any schema as well by changing the relocatable feature to true instead of false.

Thank you all for your answers and help!